# Get list of URLs inside Wordpress posts

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I need to extract all the hrefs with a specified domain name contained in links of my Wordpress post content.

Example for domain name "**stackoverflow.com**":

- https://stackoverflow.com/question/123456789/lorem-ipsum
- https://stackoverflow.com/question/123456789/dolor-sit
- https://stackoverflow.com/question/123456789/lorem-amet
- .....

Is there a way to do this via MySQL query or PHP script?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, I've tried with a PHP script that analyze all the posts in a loop and get the urls inside the content with a regular expression. But it doesn't work very well...

Comment: Feel free to show us that code, then we may be able to identify what is going wrong. That's how `SO` works, not you giving your specifications, and the community solves it for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe I found a solution:

1. Create a Wordpress page called "Links"
2. Create a PHP file called "page-links.php" in the used theme folder with tis code inside:

   ```
   function getUrls($string)
   {
       $regex = '/https?\:\/\/[^\" ]+/i';
       preg_match_all($regex, $string, $matches);
       return ($matches[0]);
   }

   $the_query = new WP_Query('posts_per_page=-1');
   while ($the_query->have_posts())
   {
       $the_query->the_post();
       $_post_id = get_the_id();
       $_post_content = get_post_field( 'post_content', $_post_id);

       $urls = getUrls($_post_content);

       foreach($urls as $url)
       {
           if (substr($url, 0, 24) == "http://stackoverflow.com")
               echo $url . '<br />';
       }

   }

   wp_reset_postdata();
   ```

Then call the Wordpress page in a bowser.
In this way all the URLs with domain "stackoverflow.com" found inside the post will be printed.